# vim/gvim's Split File Explorer not working like it used to

Tags: vim

For the life of me I can't figure this out.  I occasionally use gvim's 'Split File Explorer' from main 'Window' menu.

Normally this would open a vertical directory file listing  on the left side and a empty vertical window on the right side.  Then I could simple select a file from the left side and it would open in the right side window.

Now, when I select 'Split File Explorer' it opens only one window, but furthermore, when I select a file, it open the file in the current window.  Yes, I discovered you can use the ':E' to get back to the file explorer list.  Another point: when I have a cursor on a file, then enter ':vs .', it doesn't open the cursor-selected file - instead it opens another vertical window with directory file listings.

**How can I get the original functionality back where it opens two windows and when I select a file, it opens the file in the other window (while preserving the directory file listing on the left)?**

I'm using vim version 7.4 . Also, I have not recently alter or changed either of my .vimrc or .gvimrc files.

And one final note: just recently up-leveled to RedHat6.7 (from 6.1).  I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: The behavior you describe is the expected behavior. The question you should ask is "Why it didn't work like that before?". See `:help netrw`.